# How to upload files to a server using a URL

Tags: url, web

I was wondering is there anyway that I could have a webpage that someone would put in a URL of a image and the server that the webpage is on would automatically download the picture

Comment: Yes; that is possible.  What have you tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm asking this because I really have no clue on how you could do this.

Comment: You need to learn a server-side programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php. Might help you.